# How to view mail through a client?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, email, email-client

I just finished installing the postfix mail server and I was wondering how I can view my mail through a client rather than through command line?

What clients exist for this and which are considered to be best? Also, what are the security risks I should be aware of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to install either a web server with some webmail, or you would need to install IMAP or POP3 daemon (like for example [Dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org)), and then use any generic client (like [Mozilla thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/thunderbird)) to connect via POP3/IMAP to it.

The security risks are mostly the same: you're installing complex piece of software which is globally accessible (unless you limit it with firewall); and any security bug in such software or supporting libraries (recent security SSL issues coming to mind) will cause you grief. Also, you need to make sure not to use plaintext passwords; that usually means installing support for, and using, SSL (although there are others secure ways, like challenge-response based schemes available)